# Shortcut to actual previous line in markdown mode, or end of section

Tags: key-bindings, markdown-mode

I use `markdown-mode` and often fold the tree. I sometimes need to go to the last line of a tree, e.g. if I adjust the tree heading and then want to work at the last leaf. I suppose a shortcut can take me to the last line of a subtree. Alternatively, I could fold the subtree, go to the next heading, and go up one line (`C-p` or `previous-line`), but it goes to the previous visible line, not the actual previous line.

How can I go to the last line under a heading at point, or go to the actual previous line of the next heading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of `previous-line` (`C-h f previous-line RET`):

```
This function is for interactive use only;
in Lisp code use `forward-line' with negative argument instead.

...

If the variable ‘line-move-visual’ is non-nil, this command moves
by display lines.  Otherwise, it moves by buffer lines, ...
```

So the problem was trying to move over buffer lines when the tree was folded with visual lines. The documentation suggests `(forward-line -1)`.

Here is a function that does it, knowing that Markdown mode inherits from Outline mode. If the tree is folded, you had better move to the heading, and unfold the tree. To know whether the tree is folded, place point at the first character after the end of the heading. then you can unfold the tree ("cycling visibility") and place point at the end:

```lisp
(defun my-outline-move-end-of-subtree ()
  "Move point to the last line under this tree."
  (interactive)
  (outline-back-to-heading)
  ;; Check if tree is folded by placing point at the end of the heading
  (forward-line)
  (backward-char)
  (when (invisible-p (point))
    (markdown-cycle))
  (ignore-errors
    (outline-end-of-subtree)))
```